# ASP.NET Web API: How to do a Post back results with redirection

Tags: json, redirect, postback, asp.net-web-api

I got a Web API that performs a function and posts a JSON response back to a calling page.

This is standard Web API behaviour and works beautifully.

Now I want to modify the controller so that in addition to the post back the user is redirected back to the page on the calling web site where the result of the Web API call can be displayed  (in JSON).

So basically I want to:
(1) Server side post back the results in JSON to a page and redirect to the same page from the Web API
(2) On the caller's site, I want to display the JSON that was posted back.

How do I do this?

I already tried for many hours ...
e.g.:

```
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/json");
                client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/json");
                try
                {
                    ErrorText = client.UploadString(redirectURL, "POST", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orderresponse));
                    Response.Redirect(redirectURL);
                }
                catch (WebException err)
                {
                    ErrorText = err.Message;  //Todo - write to logfile
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the redirect on the server, instruct the client to do it by using the appropriate HTTP status code. For example:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyModel model)
{
    // handle the post
    MyResult result = ...;

    // redirect
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<MyResult>(HttpStatusCode.Moved, result);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.yourdomain.com/redirectURI");
    return response;
}
```